# What's the point of Code Review.SE?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is this site different from StackOverflow?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138/how-is-this-site-different-from-stackoverflow)

I think you can ask and answer questions for code review either on SO or programmers. What's the point of Code Review Stack Exchange?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138/how-is-this-site-different-from-stackoverflow

Answer (score 4):

Stack Overflow is for fixing code.
Programmers is for subjective questions about...programming.
Code Review is for improving code that already works.

Check out the FAQs for [CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq), [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), and [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) for more detailed stuff that points out the differences.