# Call of Duty - We're on a mission

Tags: discussion, beta-progress, unanswered-questions, voting

This is a direct reply to [Grace Note's recent CR review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/991/how-is-code-review-doing-right-now?cb=1), more precisely the following part:

(emphasis mine)

> #### Unanswered
>
> Tying in to all of the above is one of the most pressing concerns about the site I had in my own review, which is the gigantic pool of unanswered questions. There are, at the time of this writing, **1237 questions without any upvoted answers**, a whopping 1010 of which have absolutely no answers at all. **That’s over 10% of the site’s questions**, sitting untouched and barely considered to be alive. These questions range from the site’s birth in 2011 all the way to modern day 2013. **About 25% of these questions result in users never returning after a week**, from a rudimentary query.
>
> This isn’t a small number. **This is a huge chunk of the site that’s basically just a black hole of despair**, swallowing everything without giving anything back. And there’s a simple enough fix to this - clean up the unanswered questions. A large amount of what I see from these is questions that get a fair amount of comments back-and-forth when first asked, but then the entire dialogue is dropped and no one on either side follows up. **The questions essentially become abandoned, *not unlike the ultimate fate of this site* if people don’t keep up**.

Ladies & gentlemen, we have a problem. Let's fix it - that's what we do best, isn't it?

---

Go to the **Unanswered** questions: there's a counter there, showing the number of questions with no upvoted answers.

Select the [*my tags*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags) tab and **VOTE:**

<sub>(yes I have very few favorite tags - I'll fix that very soon)</sub>
[image: unanswered questions in your tags]

---

Select the *no answers* tab and **post an answer somewhere** - we have to bring this number down, ASAP - this is the *whopping 1010* Grace is talking about:

[image: questions with no answer at all]

---

Monitor the **1,237 questions without any upvoted answers** figure from Grace's post on the *votes tab*:

[image: all unanswered questions]

---

#### Your ammunition: 40 votes per day, unlimited answers.

### Every unanswered question is a zombie.

Every unvoted good answer is a target.

## Ready? **GO!**

---

#### Mission Status:

> This section tracks the metrics at regular intervals, at or around 12:00AM UTC. Each week is divided in 3 rounds (3-2-2 days), where the number of *Questions with no answers* /zombies and the number of *Questions with no upvoted answers* /targets at that point in time, is used to calculate the net score for that round; the net score is then divided by the number of days in the round.
>
> It's important to understand that those are **net** figures; they include **incoming zombies** so they are inherently skewed (downwards). We'll get a **much** better picture once the *data explorer* allows us to dig up our own data. I'm including the total number of incoming zombies at the end of the week, under the *debrief* section.
>
> Incoming zombies are acquired by searching for questions [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search) "is:question created:yyyy-MM-dd"

- **Round 0** (Grace's observations):

  - **1,010** Questions with no answers
  - **1,237** Questions with no upvoted answers
  - CR is 88% answered

---

### Week 1

- **Round 1** (2013-11-19 / 3 days):

  - **969** Questions with no answers (-41 | **13.7/day**)
  - **1,113** Questions with no upvoted answers (-124 | **41.3/day**)
  - **54** incoming
- **Round 2** (2013-11-21 / 5 days):

  - **918** Questions with no answers (-51 | **25.5/day**)
  - **1,045** Questions with no upvoted answers (-68 | **34.0/day**)
  - **41** incoming
- **Round 3** (2013-11-23 / 7 days):

  - **911** Questions with no answers (-7 | **3.5/day**)
  - **1,008** Questions with no upvoted answers (-37 | **18.5/day**)
  - **31** incoming

#### Debrief:

- **99 zombies down** | 14.1/day
- **229 targets hit** | 32.7/day
- **126 incoming zombies** | 18.0/day
- **Milestone:** CR is now 90% answered

---

### Week 2

- **Round 4** (2013-11-26 / 10 days):

  - **884** Questions with no answers (-27 | **9.0/day**)
  - **972** Questions with no upvoted answers (-36 | **12.0/day**)
  - **53** incoming
- **Round 5** (2013-11-28 / 12 days):

  - **868** Questions with no answers (-16 | **8.0/day**)
  - **944** Questions with no upvoted answers (-28 | **14.0/day**)
  - **48** incoming
- **Round 6** (2013-11-30 / 14 days):

  - **862** Questions with no answers (-6 | **3.0/day**)
  - **905** Questions with no upvoted answers (-39 | **19.5/day**)
  - **41** incoming

#### Debrief:

- **49 zombies down** | 7.0/day
- **103 targets hit** | 14.7/day
- **142 incoming zombies** | 20.3/day
- CR is now 90.9% answered

*Lock & Load people, Lock & Load!*

---

#### As of 2013-12-04 04:25 UTC...

**Status is 843 <del>unanswered questions</del> zombies, and 857 with no upvoted answers.**

## That's something to be proud of. Thanks to all who participated!!

I call that *mission accomplished*. What's next? - Guess:

[image]

843 zombies is still 843 zombies too many... keep answering!!

---

**As of 2013-12-18**, the number of remaining zombies dropped by another 100. We now stand at 743 zombies, and 785 without upvoted answers. **CR is 93% answered**.

**As of 2014-02-02**, we now stand at 754 zombies. **CR is 94% answered**.

Comment: Came for [Call of Duty](http://www.callofduty.com/).  Almost left disappointed until very last part was seen.

Comment: This is a custom *zombie mode*, you shoot zombie questions with answers, and answers with votes :)

Comment: In multiplayer mode, receiving an upvote == getting a kill (same number of points, too). :-)

Comment: I am a little surprised that you didn't say something about abandonment issues.  it has been bugging me all day I have wanted to make a joke but I can't find the right place or time or circumstance for a good one....

Comment: Seriously though, it could also help to close/delete such questions as needed.  No need to answer any that don't fit on this site.

Comment: @Malachi: I've been thinking about that, too.  Abandonment could lead to shutdown.

Comment: @Jamal: I hear that, I didn't like that talk at all.

Comment: @Malachi: Well, if it's said by a community manager, then we must listen.  They have ze numberz, after all.

Comment: That CR review is our cue - it's got all we need to know to make it, or break it.

Comment: The "spice" is that while we put energy on this big pile of .....dust, **we must still strive to address new questions within the shortest amount of time** - 8 hours *average* is bad - @Malachi this is quite possibly what's making people *not* come back.

Comment: Thanks, @codesparkle.  Everyone needs to see this post.

Comment: @Jamal part of me wonders if it shouldn't have been posted as an answer on Grace's post..

Comment: @retailcoder: I see little reason for that.  We were given our lumps, and we now know how to improve.  I see this as a *good* thing because it's one community member sparking inspiration in others.  And, of course, codesparkle agrees with this and wants it to be visible.

Comment: We're back at 89% answered!!! :D Keep it up!

Comment: @Jamal Won't... sleep.. till... 95%+......

Comment: Then you'd better clear your schedule and grab plenty of coffee...

Comment: 1226 questions with no upvoted answers is now down to 1184; 1002 questions with no answers :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11547/discussion-between-retailcoder-and-jamal)

Comment: @JamesKhoury that's an **awesome** edit! - I changed it a bit so we can track how each *round* scores :)

Comment: Ooh, I'm liking this.

Comment: @GraceNote: We're already up 3% since you've reviewed us. :-) Most of that was from answering, and also me going back and closing missed off-topic questions.

Comment: @Jamal actually we're back at 90% answered, I guess we're just *on the verge* of crossing the +3% line :)

Comment: 91% achieved! It feels great, I haven't seen that in a while.

Comment: Sorry guys but upvoting questions just to upvote is not a bad practice? I had read the question and tought to implement somenthing similar in the SO I mod but didn't like that part.

Comment: @Vitor it's more about the *answers* than the questions; there is/was lots of perfectly valid reviews/answers that didn't get any upvotes. I did vote a lot, but when I come across a bad/poor answer I post the question in chat and ask for more reviews... if I don't review it myself. The idea is to get the number of *questions with no upvoted answers* down.

Comment: Call of Duty is lame though. Can this be a quest instead? And zombies are so passe. Can they be demons?

Comment: Small report: the answer ratio leveled down to 1.8 :/

Comment: [Zombie Hunter TShirts, nice right?](http://i.imgur.com/1IwREPv.jpg) It's time for a second mission I think! The zombie count is higher than it was months ago. Must kill them all.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Every Code Review member can help us get out of beta by helping to upvote good questions and answers!  Now that Stack Exchange Data Explorer supports beta sites, here are three queries that should yield good candidates for voting:

- [Welcome intermediate users by reviewing their answers](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/160489) and [questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/161036)

  These queries finds posts from users with between 150 and 500 reputation points who have been seen recently. Those posts are likely to be at least somewhat valuable, since those users are known to have made positive contributions already. Please help bump up these members to 500!
- [Questions with only zero-score answers](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/148457)

  If a question has only zero-score answers, one of two statements should be true:

  1. Nobody has reviewed the answer(s), in which case you should help pick out the good one(s) by voting.
  2. None of the existing answers is up to par, in which case you can help by contributing a good answer!

Comment: I'd love to see CR's results with that query! ...and other queries, too! Or do we have to dig up the data dump?

Comment: Beta sites are excluded from the [data dump](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/creative-commons-data-dump-sep-11/)!

Comment: I see... so our best tools are essentially highlighted in this post then! ...*Operation Upvote*... where's the "Like" button when you need it?!

Comment: @retailcoder I never thought I would miss that thing!

Comment: @retailcoder: Gotta work on our killstreaks. ;-)

Comment: Feature request on MSO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207961/148099 — Please upvote!

Comment: @200_success look at you! First MSO post and he gets a [badge:nice-answer]! :)

Comment: @retailcoder Unlike here, they hand out reputation points like candy on StackOverflow.

Comment: @200_success you might want to take a look at this: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/conversation/statistics-on-retention-and-reputation-distribution

Answer (score 19):

### Some "memes"...

A few expressions have come up recently, thought I'd share them here (feel free to add, this is CW!)

- **Running out of ammo**: when you have exhausted all 40 votes for the day.
- **Head shot**: when you're out of ammo and [post a target in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/code-review-general-room), and then someone puts in a vote for you.
- **Waking up the dead**: when posting an answer on a zombie question causes the OP to come back to CR and *accept* your answer.
- **Killcam**: when you've just shot a zombie with a great answer, and now the zombie is still counting as a *question with no upvoted answer* so you post your own *target* in chat. Use with care, abusing the *killcam* is said to trigger thoughts of "rep-whoring".
- **Zombie looting**: when you've downvoted (upvoted?) a question that ends up being deleted (on the same day), and then you get your vote back. The *vote count* doesn't deplete though, which means *zombie looting* allows you to *appear* to have voted like 43 times on a single day, and steal the show on the [voters tab](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=week).
- **Napalm Strike** (or *Carpet Bombing Airstrike*): when you upvote the question, and **all** answers are good enough to each warrant an upvote, too.
- **Double tap:** when you answer a question that has another answer (with no upvotes).
- **(removed)**: instead of removing a chat message, why not just say `(removed)`? Started when Jamal used his vacuum cleaner on a couple of off-topic messages in the chat. Beware though, it is said *a baby unicorn dies everytime it is used*.
- **ding!**: The sound the chat makes when you ping someone.
- **theoretical**: when you're out of stars, you can still give a *theoretical star*. If you're lucky you'll even get *theoretical thanks*, so you can say *"you're theoretically welcome!"*. It's all about theory. Originated from a question that was said to have *theoretical code*, which should go into a *theoretical compiler* before being posted on Code Review.

A few of our personalities also has become a kind of meme:

- Malachi: Known for his regular [starring of messages](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=12438251#12438251)
- rolfl: Also [known as](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=12505136#12505136) ["The monkey"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=12572557#12572557). Known for being [sarcastic](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=12584243#12584243) and for having an [incredible speed in gaining reputation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31503/rolfl?tab=reputation)
- Mat's Mug: Known for his [very](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=12354932#12354932) - [intense](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=12349280#12349280) - [voting](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12575711#12575711), and his identity crises (plural ... retailcoder, lol.upvoter, ... what's next?)
- Jamal: Known for his [powers](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=12415657#12415657), [vacuum-cleaner](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=12245282#12245282), and his [compulsory editing behavior](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12581393#12581393) causing the word ["Jamalized"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13210079#13210079) to be coined.
- SimonAndréForsberg: Known for being [Swedish](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=12278991#12278991), going to bed [way too late at night](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=12348473#12348473), [having a long username](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12312985#12312985), and [taking the weekly-challenges to the next level](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12664067#12664067)
- syb0rg: Known for being a [phone-chatting](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12644389#12644389) half-human & [half-deficient-robot](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=12586881#12586881) that is a [refactoring king](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12660522#12660522).
- [Community user](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-2/stack-exchange): Known for being [a bot](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=12361271#12361271), and being [slower than humans](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=12356393#12356393) in [updating](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=12334137#12334137) the [new questions](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11760?m=12661615#12661615)

Comment: I think the Mods should let us vote on this more than once.

Comment: This answer has largely been surpassed by the [main meme collection](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1510)

Answer (score 4):

Now that Stack Exchange Data Explorer includes the beta-site statistics, it is possible to plot and manage the site activity levels....

A question was raised in Meta to discuss options: [Stack Exchange Data Explorer is up. What now, Wonderland?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1429/stack-exchange-data-explorer-is-up-what-now-wonderland)

Some of the queries that have come up are directly related to this Call of Duty:

- [Distribution of avid users by reputation tier](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/160371/distribution-of-avid-users-by-reputation-tier) (Grace Note's Query Recreated) ([and the Wonderland answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1432/31503))

  > ```
  > Reputation Threshold # Users % of Avid Users Cumulative % of Avid Users 
  > -------------------- ------- --------------- -------------------------- 
  > 150                  1159    51.8105         51.8105                    
  > 200                  828     37.0139         88.8243                    
  > 500                  146     6.5266          95.3509                    
  > 1000                 55      2.4586          97.8096                    
  > 2000                 28      1.2517          99.0612                    
  > 4000                 21      0.9388          100
  > ```

  updated 9 Feb 2014

  > ```
  > Reputation Threshold # Users % of Avid Users Cumulative % of Avid Users 
  > -------------------- ------- --------------- -------------------------- 
  > 150                  1170    51.4965         51.4965                    
  > 200                  842     37.0599         88.5563                    
  > 500                  156     6.8662          95.4225                    
  > 1000                 55      2.4208          97.8433                    
  > 2000                 27      1.1884          99.0317                    
  > 4000                 22      0.9683          100
  > ```
- [Site Activity Charts (past 60 weeks)](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/161411/site-activity-and-votegraph?Weeks=60#graph)

  Details containing raw numbers on activity.

  [image]
- [Site Activity Ratios (past 60 weeks)](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/166314/site-activity-ratios?Weeks=60#graph)

  Details containing activity expressed as a ratio. One ratio that is most significant for the Call-of-Duty is the Answers-per-Question ratio. This ratio is available on this chart, and you can track the progress of it's correction.... ;-)

  [image]
- [Questions with answers that are not upvoted](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/148457/unclosed-questions-with-only-zero-score-answers)

Answer (score 3):

The following SEDE query looks for zombies which may interest you in particular:

[Find interesting unanswered questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/4038/find-interesting-unanswered-questions)

> Looks at unanswered questions in your top 20 tags and sorts them by a combined weight which takes into account: score, askers reputation and how well you do on that particular tag