# What should be the name of our main chatroom?

Tags: discussion, chat

Our main [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/code-review-general-room) is currently called **Code Review General Room**, with *"General discussion about Code Review."* for a description.

I propose **The Zombie Hunters' Lounge**, but I'd like the community to post their ideas here (1 per post, include *why* it's the best name), the one with the highest number of votes will win!

The idea of renaming our main room came from seeing that of [Programmers.SE](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard), *The Whiteboard*.

---

#### The [Code Review General Room] has been renamed.

### [Come say "hi"!](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595)

Comment: What programmers typically do: [Naming things](http://www.itworld.com/sites/default/files/programmers_hardest_tasks-600x700.jpg).

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg And we can always *refactor/rename* later :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## The 2nd Monitor

We all [hopefully - if not you're missing out!] work with *at least* two monitors. I noticed I keep the chat window open on my 2nd monitor [almost] all the time.

Having a 2nd monitor is also quite handy during an actual peer review. I think it makes a perfectly suited name for our chatroom: representative of our site *and* of how we're [I'm?] using it!

Comment: That's it. The room shall be renamed.

Answer (score 4):

### The Duck

from:
http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RubberDucking
http://www.rubberduckdebugging.com/
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html

Comment: I loved that codinghorror blog entry! But *The Duck* sounds more like an alias for the *ask a question* page :)

Comment: Even though this isn't the name of the chat room, we do have a @RubberDuck!

Answer (score 0):

### The Zombie Hunters' Lounge

In reference to [Call of Duty - We're on a mission](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/999/call-of-duty-were-on-a-mission)... the chatroom really only became active after that post, and a number of [CR-specific "memes"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1029/23788) originated there.

I'd keep the current description though - it's *general discussion about CR*.

Comment: If you want it to be a reference to hunting, then calling it 'the lodge' seems fine, or in reference to soldiers, perhaps 'the ready room' (which may have the acronym CRRR which may also be the reviewer's 'battle cry'!)

Comment: I originally thought that "Code Review General Room" was more inviting to new users, but I have actually changed my mind. I think "The Zombie Hunters' Lounge" is good. As long as the description of being a general discussion room for Code Review remains.

Comment: Sorry to be a party pooper, but I find "Zombie Hunters' Lounge" off-putting. It doesn't sound serious enough, and is a bit gender-biased. It's also not obvious what the connection to Code Review is. As it's based on a meme, the novelty could wear off.

Comment: @200_success I agree. The room is going to keep its current name until something **amazing** comes along over here.

Answer (score -4):

From rolfl's Comment to another Question, I suggest

### The Ready Room