# So votes are good for us. How can I find answers/reviews to vote for?

Tags: discussion, faq, answers, voting

In fall 2013, we *[went on a mission](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/999/call-of-duty-were-on-a-mission)*, and **bumped the site's answered% from 88% to 93%**. As new questions flow in, the answered% has been remaining steady at 93% for several weeks, we're doing good (although *we can never have too much answering*!). The number of [questions with unvoted answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes) has dropped dramatically since the mission launched, but it's constantly pulled up as new answers come in.

Perhaps the only major roadblock towards CR's graduation, is the number of 10K users - those that will keep [access to moderator tools](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) after the site graduates. Then the number of 3K users - those that will keep the right to [cast close and reopen votes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

Stack Exchange sites are *community-moderated*. This means **WE own this site**, let's make it happen. **This year.**

So we need to generate reputation points. Luckily [we have a bunch of voters](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users?page=1&tab=voters&filter=week) (are you in that list?) - it turns out **voting is how we generate rep score**, it's what will make CR make it, or break it.

---

Great. I want to vote. I vote for interesting code review requests (/questions), well-presented ones also; I essentially upvote a question if I happen to stumble across and it's not asking for a close vote. **Questions are easy to spot** - they're listed as such on the front page.

**Answers, however, are less obvious**. Is there a way I can see the answering activity?

Comment: [We could really use your ammo.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13433092#13433092)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the ['active' view](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?tab=active).

It sorts topics reverse-chronologically, based on the time-stamp of the most recent edit:

- When a new question is created
- When a new answer is created
- When an existing question or answer is edited

It's fairly real-time: if you refresh the active the view, it will show everything up to until a few seconds (maybe a minute) ago.

Also if you click on the timestamp (circled below), it's a link to the question or answer in the topic which contains the most recent edit.

[image]

Comment: +1 because I didn't know about the timestamp link. The tab still lists *questions* though - so an edited or retagged question shows up as "recently active".

Comment: Ideally you can look at edited questions too: they may have been vandalized by editing the original code (need reverting), or improved by adding formerly-missing code (need reopening). Most of the changes are new questions and answers. Thankfully the "fastest gun in the west" syndrome (i.e. post a quick answer asap and then edit it repeatedly) doesn't seem to exist here as it does on StackOverflow.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216289/possibility-to-add-a-feed-of-all-recent-answers-to-chat-rooms/217923#217923

Answer (score 11):

> ***Is there a way I can see the answering activity?***

[@uamso-uahtan](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/142114/uamso-uahtan) has created an application in 2010, that almost *answers* our needs:

> Such a thing just happens to exist!
>
> I created a small application called stack2rss that converts API requests into RSS feeds.
> https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64927/197901

The URL for the RSS feed you want is this:

> **http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/codereview.stackexchange/answers&body=true**

---

Now you can get CR answers in your favorite RSS reader, almost in real-time!*

The good news is, you don't even need to subscribe to get the benefits: trusted users are posting links to the answers coming through that feed, into the [CR Answers](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12723/cr-answers) chatroom, created just for that.

**Q: Can I post my own answers in that room?**

A: The room was created specifically to avoid that. Please don't post your answers there. The room is opened to everyone, no restrictions - anyone can talk; discuss answers posted, perhaps discuss answer flags, or anything specifically about answers. However answer links ought to be provided by the RSS feed, to be fair for everyone.

**Q: Why aren't stack2rss-fed answers posted by the @StackExchange bot?**

A: Because chatroom feeds don't like the *stack2rss* app. They're just not working, so until [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216289/possibility-to-add-a-feed-of-all-recent-answers-to-chat-rooms) gets fulfilled (hint: upvote!), the @StackExchange bot doesn't see them.

**Q: What is this feed exactly?**

A: It's the feed of answers with recent activity - so all *new* and *edited* answers come up.

<sub>* seems there's actually a <s>6 to 8 weeks</s> *10-20 minutes* delay.</sub>

---

## Too much work. Use the 'Active' view (see accepted answer).

Answer (score 2):

### [Looking for something to shoot?](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/169776/one-vote-short)

As a 'toy query', I put the above query together....

What badges could be earned if a question, or answer, had just one more vote?

you could make someone happy with a

- [[badge:Great Question]](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/badges/42/great-question) (never been awarded... yet)
- [[badge:Reversal]](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/badges/50/reversal)
- [[badge:Guru]](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/badges/43/guru)
- [[badge:Self-Learner]](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/badges/13/self-learner)
- Reward a Zombie-hunter with [[badge:Necromancer]](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/necromancer)
- and so much more....