# Peer review a code review?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-answer

I recently made a for me, somewhat extensive code review and going through all the details I am unsure if I didn't lose myself a bit to much in reviewing.

Can we ask in someway to peer review a code review? Or can I ask a new question which points to the answer I have given on the said question, and have this peer reviewed?

I assume I can wait for comments or up and down votes, but as the question answered was over a year old, and my answer is pretty much tl;dr; I don't think anybody would read it through till the end, maybe not even the OP (if he is still around that is)

As I believe the link to the specific answer could be helpful, seeing it's really about the review itself for me, you can find it here:

[Find differences and missing elements from multiple arrays](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/141776/find-differences-and-missing-elements-from-multiple-arrays)

Comment: You can always ask in [chat]

Comment: @Vogel612 IMO asking things like this on Meta is preferable, it not only leads to a searchable Q&A on whether we allow this - which allow other users to find the answer without asking chat, but also allows for a larger audience - as lots of users don't, and won't, use SE's chat.

Comment: @Vogel612 It seems [this answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1468/54459) on a related question disagrees that one should add it to the chat

Comment: Well, if you want my peer review - it was perfectly fine. Well done!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As in any academic pursuit, the most interesting answers are ones that lead to more questions!  Some of my Code Review answers have also been reposted as questions:

- [Reddit mirror encryption challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/131684/9357)
- [Fastest possible text template for repeated use?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/102339/9357)
- ['Tis the season for gift-wrapping](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/74819/9357)
- [Celsius → Fahrenheit conversion table](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/44836/9357)
- [Just a lowly counter that turned out to be surprisingly complicated](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/44772/9357)

You may optionally use the [rags-to-riches](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rags-to-riches) tag for questions where you extensively improved someone else's code.

Comment: Yeah, I actually used that tag on my first and only question asked here (or at least, somebody added the tag). My question however not so much about the written code (though I think it is a big difference), but about the review itself. Would it make sense for me to add the link to question here?

Comment: If you have a specific concern about your post, you could make a Meta post about it. Otherwise, if you just want some general feedback, I'd mention the post in [chat].