# How do I get people to "review my review"?

Tags: discussion

I wrote a [review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/175288/event-handling-attempt-using-some-of-the-c-17-features/175319#175319) yesterday for somebody's code. However, since it is out of my specific area of expertise, I would like someone else to give it the once-over, just to make sure I haven't misdirected the author of the code. What's a good way to get this to happen when my review has been accepted?

PS - I added a caveat about my uncertainty but I'm guessing the OP didn't think much of it.

Comment: Related: [Peer review a code review?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8413) - However, your answer didn't show any code changes, so I don't think that you could follow the same advice as the linked question. It may be a good idea to say how this question differs from the linked one however, in-case people VTC duplicate.