# Code Review Graduation

Tags: discussion, beta-progress

I am pleased to announce that effective from September 22, Code Review has graduated! It has taken a bit of time for this announcement to filter through the red tape, so, today was the day we found out.

Let's use this as a place to discuss, celebrate, and otherwise commiserate.

**Notes:**

Code Review is graduating, and is now in the (long) queue to go through the graphic design, etc. When that is all complete (probably in 6-8 months), then the higher graduate-level privileges/permissions will be applied, the new design added, and moderator elections held.

So, this is to say that the graduation is now inevitable, but the actual application is delayed.

Comment: Where's our new design? Where's the increased privileges? What's going on!?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg - see my updates.

Comment: So, there's so much inflation in the weeks that they have turned to months now? Or is it because we're in the eternal september?

Comment: I have been trying to think of an analogy for this state we are in, but the best I can think of is that, like students writing final exams, we have now written the exams, they have been marked, and we have passed, but the graduation ceremony still has to be scheduled, and only then will we get our certificates, and 'honours'.

Comment: Hell Yeah,Also see this question http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1572/what-are-the-advantages-of-graduation 
(Thanks Monkey)

Comment: I was starting to fear something was going on behind the scenes with doubts towards CR. Glad I was wrong! Woooooooo!

Comment: Wait, does this mean that we will lose certain privileges after the transition?

Comment: @EthanBierlein - it means that the thresholds for all permissions will be adjusted, yes, and for everyone with less than 20K rep, their privileges will be reduced, yes. This is the 'normal' process for graduating sites... the length of time that Code Review has been in beta makes it harder to accept, though.

Comment: You should also note that the change is still some time in the future that has yet to be determined, it could still be a long way away... I don't know.

Answer (score 26):

Wait.. You're kidding, right?

## CONGRATS GUYS! WE DID IT!!!!

Comment: The last time I said that we had a terrible bug. So I'm glad it's you ! I hope we have more luck this time!

Answer (score 25):

My birthday is on September 22nd, and if this is true it is truly the best birthday gift I could ever have asked for!

## Thank you, StackExchange for this birthday gift!

Answer (score 23):

I'll say goodbye to my privileges, but I'm still very happy about this!

It was about time CR got on the map. (The... SE Map)

## I NEED TO ADD CAPS LOCKED THINGS TOO. YAY!!!

Comment: Don't say goodbye to your privileges, say hi to be able to gain new ones again :)

Comment: That is one good way to see it ;)

Comment: I have to admit that I actually miss that part of being a 20K user :)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Well you can always bounty 500 rep on a lot of question !

Answer (score 19):

## Our Mission is Complete

The Mission that we chose to accept - [Call of Duty - We're on a mission](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/999/18427)

Our terms of engagement were nothing less than Victory; we have succeeded and overcome the damage of the lull that preceded us into battle, we now stand victorious.

---

The Battle against the Zombies is a different story, let them not overcome us again, keep firing, keep stockpiling your ammunition, keep recruiting new warriors, keep engaging the Enemy!

---

Congratulations Code Review!

Comment: "keep stockpiling your ammunition" Does that mean we should *stop* voting? :-)

Comment: Means we should all keep learning our languages as well as new languages. :-)

Comment: This post makes me feel like I have just completed a game and are now going to watch the credits.

Comment: Time to remind everybody that we're actually still on a mission.