# What ever happened to Code Review "graduating"?

Tags: discussion, beta-progress

Last September, Meta got the triumphal announcement that "[Code Review SE is graduating!](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2545/code-review-se-is-graduating)".

But eight months later, the site still looks and acts very much like a beta site.  It even has "Beta" in the header. And privilege levels and such haven't changed as the discussions of graduation suggested they would.

What gives?  Has SE changed its collective mind?  Or is graduation a much longer process timewise than i had the impression it was?

Comment: I guess that it has to do with the fact that there aren't that many designers.