# An answer feed in The 2nd Monitor

Tags: feature-request, chat

Currently in [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor), there is a "recent questions" feed that is displayed by our very own Captain Obvious.

Would it be a good idea to have a "recent answers" feed, too?

Comment: CR History alert: We used to have this, more or less, once in a while, in a separate chat room: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/12723/2014/1/29 Note that Mat's Mug posted *all* answers *manually* for quite a while.

Comment: After a while, syb0rg made a chat bot that could post answers automatically to chat. See [the CR question with the bot code](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/44511/31562)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## No

I think The Mission is about bringing down the zombie count. That's a much smaller subset than all the answers. I think all the answers would be too much. On days when users pimp several answers, *that* already feels too much sometimes.

Keep in mind that the main purpose of the 2nd monitor is to discuss site business. All the answers would be surely too much noise and annoying.

Answer (score 6):

## No

Users who are regulars here are going to know other users who are regulars, and may feel strongly obliged to vote on another regular's answer if they seed it come up in the feed. This leads to falsely-earned reputation.

Comment: +1 for a good cause.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes

Many answers go unnoticed and this will help in [The Mission](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/999/call-of-duty-were-on-a-mission) because users will be more aware of answers worthy of votes.

Comment: +1 for a good cause.

Answer (score -2):

## Yes-ish

I think this is a good idea, but I don't think we want to clutter up chat with recent answers. Rather than *all* recent answers, maybe we could post answers that meet the following criteria:

1. Answer must have at the maximum, zero votes.
2. Answer must be older than one day. (This can be up for debate.)
3. Answer can be accepted, or not accepted.

Or in other words, only zombies. Since @RoboSanta already does most of this, maybe his functionality could just be expanded.

Comment: I disagree with this. 1. These feeds update fairly infrequently. And, answers aren't posted *every* second. There won't be much clutter at all. 2. Your current solution would apply quite a lot of answers, and it seems like the answers you are describing are already handled by Robosanta.