# I was the shield that guarded the flags of users

Tags: discussion, moderators

I became a moderator [in the first election](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/election/1) four years ago but it is now time to step down.

I came here to Code Review in November 2013, after browsing the site for a few days I posted my first comment, and later my first answer. [I found chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12239484#12239484) and found the wonderful people [Mathieu](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12241052#12241052), [Jamal](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/22222/jamal), and [Malachi](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12193595#12193595). Just a few days after, [rolfl joined as well](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12277946#12277946). I arrived just in time for [The Mission](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/999/31562) where I was one of the regulars who helped Code Review go through graduation.

I have experienced a lot during my time at Code Review, everything from [starring lol's](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1629/31562) to learning new languages and techniques, and participating in community challenges. I have also experienced a lot during my four years as a moderator. I have seen the community grow and change, but as Nelly Furtado sings - [All good things come to an end](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4pBo-GL9SRg).

There's happened a lot of (unfortunately not very positive) things in my personal life recently that you just wouldn't believe me if I told you. I have now reached a point in my life where I value many other things more than Code Review, one of which includes organizing board game meetups IRL with the purpose of helping people make new friends (very international crowd). Code Review Stack Exchange will still have a special place for me. I have learnt a lot here, and I will continue to post interesting questions and good answers every now and then.

I'd like to thank a few people of the community for making the past years much enjoyable.

- [Mathieu](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/23788/mathieu-guindon), Code Review's former cheerleader. Without you there wouldn't have been a mission and maybe we would still have been in beta. When I was elected, Mathieu was elected at the same time, and our performance in the election was pretty much inseparable.
- [Marc-Andre](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/28156/marc-andre), it's always a pleasure seeing you write "Hello everybody! Have a nice day!"
- [rolfl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31503/rolfl), Code Review's own monkey. You are a wise and valuable monkey and friend.
- My current moderator friends, [rolfl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31503/rolfl), [Vogel612](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/37660/vogel612), [Jamal](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/22222/jamal), [Malachi](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/18427/malachi). Thank you for your assistance, support and for the collaboration.
- My former moderator friends, [200_success](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9357/200-success), [Mathieu](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/23788/mathieu-guindon), [janos](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/12390/janos). It was a privilege and a pleasure working with you all.
- My friends [Phrancis](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/42632/phrancis), [Marc-Andre](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/28156/marc-andre), [skiwi](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/32231/skiwi) and the others in the Coding Projects chat-room.
- [Duga](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/51786/duga), my only child and bot. Code Review just wouldn't be the same without her. And don't worry, she will keep being just as much of a moderator as she's always been.
- Everyone who voted for me in the first election.
- [Mast](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/52915/mast), [EBrown](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/73844/der-kommissar), [Peilonrayz](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/42401/peilonrayz), and others from the community that I have spent many hours with in The 2nd Monitor.

If there's anything I would like to leave behind me it is to encourage you all to comment, comment, comment. A good and friendly comment can make a big difference. (Yes, it is possible to enforce rules and still be friendly. Trust me.)

I was a sworn moderator of the Code Review watch. For four years I have served. And now my watch has ended.

Comment: To bad you are stepping down. Wish you all the best.

Comment: Comment! Comment! Comment! Indeed. I know that you won't be so far away from Code Review that we will really miss you, right? I also consider you a friend, and will keep in touch.

Comment: Love the GoT references! You've been a great mod, thanks for everything you've done for all these years, ...even if a lot of it was in Java.

Comment: And another of the old guard leaves :( Good luck.

Comment: You have always been a very fair and kind moderator. Your legacy will live on. Thank you Simon!

Comment: mhmmm... I'm puzzeled... a diamond is informing us that he's stepping down and gets for his post upvotes. Does this mean that each +1 is like _yes, please go!_ and each -1 like _no, please stay!_ What is the voting logic here? Are you/we voting on the opening line or the rest below it?

Comment: @t3chb0t I've been wondering the same things honestly. These types of posts often get a big number of votes (see for example Mathieu's decision last year). I would guess that a +1 means "Let's give this more attention"

Comment: It has been 4 years already? Time flies. All the best, and thank you for your years of service.

Comment: Thank you for your hard work. One of the first pull requests I ever did was to https://github.com/Zomis/ReviewPrepare :)

Comment: @SimonForsberg Good luck with everything in your life :D

Comment: @SimonForsberg It means, "Thank you for your service, and we wish you well in whatever you're going to pursue."

Comment: @jpmc26 Aww, thanks! Do I then want to know what the -1 I got means?

Comment: @SimonForsberg Probably that they don't want you to go.

Comment: @jpmc26 Or possibly the opposite :) Who knows? Either way, I'll be going anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Simon's diamond officially gone to the trophy shelf as of today, I just want to add:

## Thank you!

Thank you again for your years of moderatorship!

Answer (score 25):

We wish you well, Simon, and don't be a stranger!

Where do we go from here?

This is just a brief administrative note to say that the Stack Exchange staff and the rest of the mod team are in discussions about what the next steps are, what the needs of the community may be, and so on.

At this point in time no decisions have been made and it will probably take some time (weeks) before any action (if any) is taken.

Note that a moderator stepping down does not automatically trigger an election. Other factors are taken in to account. I only say this because I imagine that will be one of the first questions asked: "Will there be an election", and the answer is: "We don't know".

Comment: To be fair, we did have another mod step down recently as well. That said, we should be fine because we still have 4 left.

Comment: To be clear: it turns out I'm thinking of when Mat, 200, and Janos stepped down some time ago.