# Does this question belong on Code Review? Should it go to Code Golf?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-topic

I posted [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/43756/is-there-an-easier-way-to-find-the-index-of-the-first-letter-in-a-string) about how to rewrite a C# algorithm in fewer lines of code, preferably using extension methods, which prompted a discussion in the comments about whether it  was appropriate for Code Review.  I'd originally considered posting it to StackOverflow, but then I read [this Meta answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/141/38318) from  Jeff Atwood, and decided that since I was asking about how to make my code look more elegant, not about fixing a bug, it belonged on Code Review.

I didn't intend it as inviting people to solve a puzzle, and while I'd like to make it shorter, I still want it to be readable and easily modified, so I don't think it's a Code Golf question.

Looking at the Code Review FAQ, though, I'm not sure if it belongs here.  I tend to think of extension methods as  a cleaner way to program in .NET, but I suppose there's a difference between trying to write code that "looks better" and actually trying to implement best practices.

This kind of thing comes up for me a lot in my work, so I'd like to get some input about whether or not I should post these sorts of "beautifying" questions to Code Review, or if I should only ask about software design principles or algorithm efficiency.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the close queue I can see that three people voted to close and three voted to leave open, meaning that the question is gone from the close queue. Even though it has four close votes, I consider it on-topic. Here's why:

- Your question contains code
- You wrote that code
- It looks like actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code or example code
- You want the code to be good code (i.e. not code-golfing, obfuscation, or similar)
- The code works
- Even though you're not explicitly asking for feedback about any or all facets of the code, you are also not not-asking about it (double-negation FTW!)

The four close voters has used this close reason:

> Questions asking for code to be written to solve a specific problem are off-topic here as there is no code to review.

I have to disagree with these voters because:

1. You're not asking for code to be written, you're asking about if there is an easier way to do what you are doing
2. The problem to solve has already been solved, you're just asking about how it can possibly be solved easier / in a different way
3. There is code to review

Conclusion:

Your question is on-topic.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a short guideline I use as to what belongs where:

- **Software Engineering** - Algorithms, concepts, maybe minimal code or math to clarify.
- **StackOverflow** - Broken, non-working code.
- **CodeGolf** - A puzzle is given. Everyone else does the code, as short as possible.
- **CodeReview** - You need working code for review, which is being subjected to:

  - **Readability** - Code can be understood. *This would include beautifying it and keeping the code as short and simple but still readable*. I think it's this that keeps the code from getting "golfed". For instance, I can do some very complex ternary to vastly shorten my code, but that sacrifices readability.
  - **Scalability** - The code is easily extended with features. Golfed code typically just addresses one issue, the puzzle. Scalability, however, requires your code to be adaptable, and would require additional logic to handle extras.
  - **Maintainability** - The code can easily be debugged and fixed. Golfed code is hard to read, and not good for maintainability.
  - **[some other factors]** - Efficiency, least CPU cycles, least overhead, proper use of syntax, conventions, better algorithms etc.

Comment: This would be a good general answer to link people to if Programmers was also in the list. Unfortunately though, I don't think that you're answering the OP's specific question about whether or not that particular question is on-topic here or not.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I just created this list as a guideline. I think his "beautifying" query belongs under readability.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot imagine any question where it's - given that it is suitable for at least one of them and these two sites are the only choices - ambiguous if it should be posted on Codereview or Codegolf. The latter one is purely for fun, and the only objective is to write as short code as possible by any means possible. Performance, readability, memory usage and such is not even considered. Any suitable answer on Codegolf would be a very bad answer on Codereview.

Comment: There are situations where either site thinks it's a better fit on the other. Usually that means it's a bad fit on both.

Comment: @Mast I clarified a bit