# What tips would you suggest to increase tag activity?

Tags: discussion, questions, publicity

I honestly looked for a dupe for this but could not find one. If it did exist I would assume it was tag-centric so I didn't notice.

I have been doing [powershell](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powershell) on SO for some time now and have a good grasp on the basics. I wanted to come over here to give people a little help (which I have so far once). The PowerShell tag here is not a busy one. I was curious to know what I could do, as a gifted amateur in that tag, to try and increase activity here?

I could personally try and create more content in a Q&A format but CodeReview.SE does not seem like a site that lends well to people answering their own questions? I could just put up some of my own complete code snippets here for people to look at but I don't think I have a lot of worthy questions based on them. I suppose I could also leave comments on SO more but I could see that as being noise that could be deleted and get me flagged depending.

I want to be of use here!

Comment: You may be interested in this post: http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/a/1170

Comment: Do you want me to post a PowerShell FizzBuzz sometime?  I'm sure I wouldn't do something right.

Comment: @Hosch250 I will answer that question once I take the time to properly understand what it is. holroy most likely told me what i need to know but i'm too tired to understand.

Comment: @Matt See the [tag:fizzbuzz] description.

Comment: Oh my god.... I get it now. I thought it was somesort of site feature or something... I mean I guess it is but I get it now. I think I will post one first if you dont beat me to it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I could personally try and create more content in a Q&A format but CodeReview.SE does not seem like a site that lends well to people answering their own questions?

Funny you mention *create more content* - that was exactly my CommunityBuilding.SE answer to *[How do I start an active userbase for a tag in on a question and answer site (like Stack Exchange)?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/1168/402)*

The [vba](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vba) tag has 264 questions and 494 answers today, but that tag's top **three users** contributed 56 questions and 252 answers out of that number.

When I decided I'd do everything I can to get the [vba](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vba) tag up to 100 questions to make it *badgeable*, I started with *selfies*. How many? I don't know, I never counted. I never held back from posting them.

Eventually, *another user* answers one of your questions. *Get them on board!*

[image: 1]

---

Get into chat, meet the people, watch the tag; keep an eye on the tag's [top users](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/powershell/topusers) page, *get to the top* and make [powershell](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powershell) a thing: by posting working scripts, you have a wonderful opportunity to *teach* readers on this site enough to try their hand at it!

[<s><sub><sup>wait, there's no FizzBuzz in PowerShell?!</sup></sub></s>](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fizzbuzz+powershell)

Comment: +1 for no  FizzBuzz...  I've done very little in Powershell, but we'll try helping out, @Matt

Comment: I guess I could post code I made, what seems like, years ago. Look at it myself now and, if not one else answers, critique my own work on my improved standards.

Comment: What the heck is FizzBuzz?

Comment: Sounds like the Mug is giving me a green light on this one.

Comment: @Matt [tag:fizzbuzz] :-)

Comment: Search for it, and you'll find FizzBuzz implementation on this site for a rather esoteric choice of languages... In short it is a counting algorithm where one replaced numbers dividable by 3 with Fizz, and dividable with 5 with Buzz, and both if dividable by both...

Comment: I just saw this question and was going to basically post this answer. I'm mobile, so I can't right now, but there's a relevant story about this journey for the [tag:vba] tag in the CRonichles chat room somewhere. A link may be appropriate.

Comment: Aww man. I just read that quote. Seems like ages ago. I actually lol'd (and *maybe* teared up a bit).

Answer (score 13):

To help sweeten the pot, I've offered bounties totalling +400 on three unanswered [powershell](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powershell) questions.

I've [advertised](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26797128#26797128) the bounties in the Server Fault chat room.  Please help spread the word as well.

Comment: How did you decide how much of a bounty to add to each question?

Comment: I picked the top three most highly voted unanswered questions, then estimated the difficulty of reviewing them, based mostly on the length of the code.

Answer (score 6):

### Question Quality

This is something that I consider very important.

I recently wrote a [guide for how to post a good question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6429/31562). Some parts of that post that can help in this case is:

- **Description** - If you describe what it is that you are doing, then you will help me understand the code
- **Describe the details and your approach** - If you describe *how* you are doing it, then you also help me understand the code
- **Don't assume that everyone knows what you are talking about** - Make people learn something just by reading your question. (There are a lot of Stack Overflow questions where I learn precisely what I need to know just by reading the *question* rather than the answers)

Include a link to a tutorial or two about the language in your post. If you are using a specific feature/syntax that are unfamiliar to most people, link to a page that describes that feature or syntax.

By writing high quality questions, you might just convince me to learn the language and to try to review your code.

Answer (score 6):

Community ads will be activated in a few weeks. I've created [this one](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6552/23788) to raise awareness, when the ads are active, it will be shown in the sidebar if it gets to 6 upvotes.

[image: PowerShell tag community ad]

Comment: I like it. Hope we get the votes. I assume that there is no set expiry for the candidacy of this ad?

Comment: Ads usually expire mid-December, so there's plenty of time :-)

Comment: it has the required 6 as of now.

Comment: @RubberDuck I think you mean.. *now*

Comment: @Raystafarian lol, click that picture, the *actual* ad is on the [meta-tag:community-ads] posting, currently at +8 ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug ha! I had both questions open and got confused.