# Can I ask to review my ebuild or rpmspec file?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

Does the site welcome questions about writing [ebuilds](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Ebuild), rpmspecs or simular files for advanced package management? While it's relatively easy to come up with a working script, making a high quality package which satisfies current best practices and traditions of the specific distro may be incredibly hard for a newcomer.

Are there people who can answer questions like these here, or it's better to ask for help in the distro's community?

Comment: Are 'ebuilds' like Arch AUR PKGBUILDs, which contain standard bash?

Comment: @Peilonrayz: yes, they're essentially the bash scripts which are sourced by the package manager. However, Gentoo Portage comes with a number of helpers (groupped into so-called eclasses) and other disto-specific things like build phases.

Comment: If it's working code, it's reviewable. If a tag doesn't exist, it can be created. IDK about whether there are people that can review [ebuilds] scripts, but to start community building there always needs to be a first. Not too long ago there were just a handful of PowerShell questions - now there are enough for tag badges to be awarded in that tag. Same story with VBA. See if [this answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6511/23788) helps =)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, questions like that would be on-topic.  I would consider them similar to [makefile](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/makefile) and [dockerfile](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dockerfile) questions.  We encourage you to post your scripts for review.