# Are hard questions forbidden?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I asked [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/146193/red-black-tree-appears-to-be-slower-than-stdmultimap) and it was closed.

Before I asked that question I asked on meta.stackexchange.com which community would be suitable to ask the question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286168/stack-exchange-site-for-code-optimization).

I don't understand what is unclear about my question. **Review my code** and find out why it is **slower** than a comparable container type. What's unclear about that?

Comment: For what it's worth, I think the question after your edits for clarity should be fine for reopening. I don't think the difficulty of the question is necessarily related to why it was closed, there are plenty of difficult questions out there.

Answer (score 8):

No, there's nothing wrong with hard question. And by hard I mean *complicated code*.

There is however something wrong with *unclear* questions, which is what your question was closed as ("unclear what you are asking"). While it is *hard* to review such questions, it is a different type of hard.

You can ask for a review about all kinds of [neural networks](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/93690/31562), [complicated implemented algorithms](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/62383/31562), [over-engineered code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/53921/31562), etc. as long as you explain the things a reviewer need. What is the code doing? What is class `xyz` that is needed by parts of the code you posted? Answer such questions and you do not need to worry about the code being too hard to review.

See also [Simon's guide for a good Code Review question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6429/31562)