# How should I ask this big question?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I am currently working on one of my first projects with Python and my first project with PyQT. I would like to post this as a question, to see if there are any improvements I can make.

The project is quite big however (not sure if big enough to score for the [three zombie heads](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2320/140805)), consisting of two parts. Two classes that handle the logic (166 LOC) and one for the GUI (320 LOC). The GUI is what I would like the most feedback on, but that wouldn't work without providing the other two classes.

I am not sure how to go on. Should I provide the code for the logic first, and then have the GUI reviewed in a different question? I am afraid that if I dump it all in one question it would be a bit too much. On the other hand, if I ask the GUI separately, it wouldn't be able to run on its own.

Comment: soo ... I'd score that at 2 zombie heads. We do semi-regularly see questions with up to a dozen classes, with every class in the low hundreds of lines. **that**'s 3 Zombie heads :)

Comment: IMO 500 LOC is only one zombie. I don't know of any PyQT pros in the Python tag, so possibly add another zombie. Either way, I think it's quite likely to be answered, even if you post all of the code.

Answer (score 1):

On Code Review we have a bigger character limit than on other SE sites. Nevertheless having questions with a lot of code isn't always the best.

If you can provide a github link or similiar which e.g points to the GUI part of the code I would suggest posting the logic part first together with the link.

If you later want to get your GUI code to be reviewed as well you can do it the other way round by posting a link either to the logic part or to the then hopefully answered question.

Comment: That's what I figured. Do you have a ballpark figure of what would be *a lot of code*?

Comment: For me that question https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/172027/document-management-properties-and-searching has too much code in it. But thats just my opinion.

Comment: Just as an example

Comment: That's around the same length as mine would be combined. So that is good to know.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam If you go this route, make sure you create a link to the correct revision of your GitHub. Say someone else finds your question 2 weeks later and still wants to review it, a link to a specific revision would make things easy.