# How can I improve this question about asyncio?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions

I recently asked [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/177547/asyncio-with-live-update-and-abort-capabilities) question on Code Review which was ill-received and got 4 close votes for being off-topic. I believe the main problem to be that I used a dummy function for a third party API which is not very common. I did (in an edit) provide a link to the page describing its functionality and a way to download it if interested. This function is however not important for the core part of the question (`asyncio` and `QThread`).

I would like to improve upon my question and was wondering what the main remaining issues are.

Comment: Have you read [Simon's Guide to posting a good question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6429/31562)?

Comment: @SimonForsberg. I did indeed as well as the off-topic faq. `on-topic`: I did strip/replace a part, would it be better to put in an import of rarely used lib (like in the real code)? `Motivation`: I hope I made it clear that I'm new to multithreading and my code doesn't scale well. `Usage`: You are right, I will include a few screen shots in a minute. `Description`: I hope I did that. `Descripe details`: I hope I  did that. `What about`: I included link to 3rd party API. `Interesting`: Hard to tell. `PrtScn`: Will add. `Limitations`: Not that I know of. Did I miss something?