# Why was my question put on hold for Authorship of Code even though everything was written by me?

Tags: support

I have [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/223595/generic-macro-generated-interval-heap-in-c) that was put on hold because some people **thought** the code was not made by me, putting the question on hold and so I got no feedback or code reviews for it because some people simply don't care! I've spent 4 days reading through papers and other people's code to understand how an interval heap works and decided to put it on Code Review because it is one of the first data structures that I've made that doesn't have a lot to talk about.

How can I prove that the code was written by me or how can I remove it from being on hold?

I have several questions on Code Review that all point to the same code base on GitHub, which is a a project of my own and even after 3 questions, all containing the same topics (like data structures or something related to the C language), why does [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/223595/generic-macro-generated-interval-heap-in-c) has to be cherry picked and put on hold?

Comment: I apologize. I was under the impression that it was taken from a random GitHub account. I've voted to re-open. With that impression removed, it's a great question.

Comment: I was also under the impression that it was taken from a random GitHub account. The wording in the question makes it appear to be code you copied from someone else's account. I have voted to reopen the question.

Comment: Sorry for my wording in this question. I must say I got a bit frustrated when I went to investigate why that question had no more activity. Thank you all for clarifying things. [Here is my apologies](https://github.com/LeoVen/C-Macro-Collections/commit/09ebb1eae8239a1b98d08116721827e2dd754e54).

Comment: @LeoVen You might also be interested in [using a "reviewed" "shield"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/95459/31562)

Comment: Lots of links to "this" and "here" can mislead readers that those are hiding your actual code (which you know is off-topic).  You can help us all by giving the links more informative names.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Someone flagged your post for "should be closed" -> "off-topic" -> "Authorship of code" which caused it to be put into the [close vote review queue](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/close/118684) where 5 users voted to close and 1 voted to leave open.

Possible lessons hopefully to be learned:

- Close voters can help out by asking clarifying questions - "Is this code yours?" "Where did you find this code?"
- When voting to close for "Authorship of code" because the code seemingly comes from a "random GitHub repository", close voters can try to check the user of the GitHub account with the Stack Exchange account, if there are any connections between these two (username, profile pictures, linking between them, etc.) then I would assume that everything is in order.
- When asking a question, it can be extra helpful to show that you are aware of the site rules and that your post passes the rules. See also [this guide to posting a good question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6429/31562)

Now I've put in the 5th reopen vote (didn't even have to use my moderator powers) so your question is now reopened. Sorry for the inconvenience, you did the right thing to bring the mistake to our attention.