# Put on-hold and off topic 2 time

Tags: support, specific-question, scope, asking-questions

I have a question about my Code Review Stack Exchange post: [Driver for Sensor payload Decoder](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/225928/driver-for-sensor-payload-decoder)

I have been trying to get some suggestions on the code which I have written after learning about drivers. Tried in other forums came here only after their suggestion. Can agree at first I might not post it the way it follows the rules. But I have done changes of whatever I understood from mere 2 comments and rules to post a query. And still being put on hold without any comments wouldn't help me understand in anyway of what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: There's a yellow banner under your question, referring to (among other things) the [help/on-topic]. This does not answer your question?

Answer (score 5):

At the moment of writing this, your question is an improperly formatted code dump without explanation of the requirements or the problem you solved with it. We are not magicians, we can't read your mind, so we don't have enough to work with here. The question is not reviewable.

That's why it got closed.

Is it salvageable? Yes. But you'll have to put some work in.

The specific close reason for your question states we're lacking context. This means we need to see more about the code and how it's used. With a bit of an explanation of why you wrote this (what problem does it solve).

Note:

- For general information about what's on-topic, see the [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
- For general information on how to get the best out of asking questions, see our [faq](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq): [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915)

Clarification:

You state the following:

> Put on-hold and off topic 2 time

Not on Code Review. According to the [timeline](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/225928/timeline) it was closed once. Are you referring to [your Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57427103/1014587) instead? Keep in mind Code Review and Stack Overflow are considered different sites, with different scopes, and your question got closed on both by different users.

#### Update:

The question got heavily edited and is now reopened.

Comment: First time when I posted it was put off-topic. Second time, after reading the comments and I made the changes I rephrased the title.

Comment: @Hemanth I would also recommend reading [this guide to how to post a good question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1954/checklist-for-how-to-write-a-good-code-review-question/6429#6429)