# How can I explain my code in Code Review

Tags: support, questions

I am new to Code Review and I am really enthusiastic to post my code for the problems that took me hours to crack. It has really helped me upgrading my poor logic and unoptimized code blocks and overall it would help the other people as well. But the problem is that I have to put hours commenting out little things in my code. And I think no one is going to read through uncommented blocks of code and even if they, then they might not actually get flaws in my approach. I feel I have to write a lot in the Body Section of the Problem to make others understand what I am actually trying to do.

Please can someone tell me a much better or time saving way of explaining the problem maybe,
through a small YouTube video that I can paste the link of or through recording my voice and video and attaching it in the body.

Please help me on this matter and don't just see and go away as I really want to contribute to the community but describing complex logic and problems is getting way harder.

Answer (score 8):

I'll try to answer your question line by line.

> But the problem is that I have to put hours commenting out little things in my code.

Please refrain from making modifications to your code. Your code should be working before you get it reviewed, so please don't comment anything out or add comments that weren't there in the original version. If you don't have enough comments, that could be pointed out in a review. If you have too many comments, that could be pointed out in a review. You changing the code just to post it doesn't tell us what your real code looks and doesn't provide you with the insights you required about the comments used. Instead, please tell us what problem you've solved and your approach in solving it as a description in the question body.

> And I think no one is going to read through uncommented blocks of code and even if they, then they might not actually get flaws in my approach.

That's not a problem. A lot of the questions that do well, have zero or very little comments. Add a description of what your code is supposed to be doing and your approach in the question body, but don't change the comments in the code.

> I feel I have to write a lot in the Body Section of the Problem to make others understand what I am actually trying to do.

Yes, that's how it's supposed to be. Having an explanation just as big as your code is not necessarily a problem, although it's possible you have a verbose style of writing that could be more to the point.

> Please can someone tell me a much better or time saving way of explaining the problem maybe, through a small YouTube video that I can paste the link of or through recording my voice and video and attaching it in the body.

YouTube videos are actually a very poor way of describing your code. Please don't do that. There are multiple problems with that, one of them being that it doesn't fit with the policy that questions should be standing on their own. Code that's behind a link does often *not* get reviewed and if too much of it is behind a link it's grounds for closure. Descriptions which are behind a link can and will be skipped, making your question unclear (also grounds for closure). Instead, please look at a couple of [recent, well received questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+score%3A20+created%3A2y) and see if you can find a pattern with them.

> Please help me on this matter and don't just see and go away as I really want to contribute to the community but describing complex logic and problems is getting way harder.

Posting good questions isn't easy. Being able to properly describe the problem you're solving and how you approached it *by itself* is already a great teaching tool. If it's hard, make sure you do properly understand the subject good enough. If you don't understand what you're doing good enough to tell us what you did, how are we supposed to understand what you're doing and help you with it?

It's also a matter of practice. Posting the first couple of questions the right way takes a lot of time. It gets a lot easier over time, but I still spend half an hour *minimum* just to properly phrase, explain and format a question. All to increase how useful it is to the rest of the community and to increase the likelihood of receiving a useful answer.

Reviewers are spending their free time on reviewing questions and code in questions. The least you could do is make it easy on them by providing the context they require in a comprehensible manner.

You're getting help for free, that doesn't mean it comes cheap.

Helpful reading material:

- [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915)
- [Checklist for how to write a good Code Review question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1954/52915), [this answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6429/52915) is particularly useful for new users.

Comment: A big thanks to you Mast, you can understand the feeling of frustration when you want  your code to be best reviewed but ended up getting least responses and couldn't explain it in the way that it should have been . And yes you are right ,I think i have a verbose style :D