# Trying to make sure I ask an apropriate request for code review

Tags: discussion

I have not had the best of luck asking for code reviews.  Mostly my fault for not really knowing what I don't already know, and not being able to correctly convey what I am trying to ask about.

I have broken up a coding project I am trying to improve, so I can focus on only a small subset of components at a time, to try and make improvements easier, one step at a time.  I know my code has some unintended issues, and I am trying to improve it to be more professional, and maybe useful to someone else.

With that in mind, are there any recommendations, beyond showing all code, correct formatting etc, that you all can offer.  For example should I add comments with specific concerns I have with sections of code I am asking for review?

Thanks in advance for any advice offered!

Comment: There's the [help/on-topic], [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions), [Checklist for how to write a good Code Review question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1954/checklist-for-how-to-write-a-good-code-review-question), etc. Do those answer your question?

Comment: @Mast - sort of. I reread all of those before the last post I made. The impression I had was because it was a large project I could link the GitHub code, while posting the specific code I wanted reviewed.  While the rest was available for context. That question was closed. After revision then closed denied reopening. It wasn’t reopened until I posted as much as could be included. Never got a response. So I deleted it while I made some reworked changes. While I can see in posts that approach is acceptable I also see in others where it isn’t. So it confusing with individual interpretations.

Comment: Larger codebases always have a higher risk not getting answered. It's much more work for the reviewers. You have 2 questions on the main site. 1 from '20, answered (did you know there's a checkmark next to an answer so you can mark it as accepted? Is there a reason the answer wasn't sufficient for you?). 1 from '22, self-deleted a couple of months ago a day after it was re-opened. If you delete a post, it's not going to get answered.

Comment: @Mast, good call outs.  I delete the last one, because I think the request was too broad.  It really should have been broken down into some specific component requests.  The earlier one, did answer the specific question.  Just used the BETA staging ground on Stack Overflow.  That may actually resolve the issue I am asking about.  It lets you refine the question to be more meaningful I think.

Comment: The problem with breaking out specific components is they can easily lose context and become difficult to review as a result. Linking to the context is usually insufficient--the subcomponent should be standalone, as if it were a single app/module/function/class with all dependencies available. If you have a large app and you want to receive a review on a small portion of it, try to make that portion standalone, toss in a few tests to show how it works, assist reviewers in running it, and probably mention what it does in the larger project for context.

Comment: Somehow I've not seen your question until now. Could you link me to the question which you're referencing to earlier? "While the rest was available for context. That question was closed." Doing so would likely be able to open my eyes to what went wrong.